# How to draw on just a portion of the screen with SpriteBatch in libgdx?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

When I do this:

```Java
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4().setToOrtho(0, 320, 0, 240, -1, 1));
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 0, 0);
spriteBatch.end();
```

`SpriteBatch` will draw the `textureRegion` onto the coordinate system 320-240 that I have specified to the whole screen. Say I want to draw with the same coordinate system 320 240 but only **on the left half of the screen** (which means everything will be scaled down horizontally in the left side, leaving the right half of the screen black), how can I do?

Answer (score 6):

You're going to want to use the ScissorStack. Effectively, you define a rectangle that you want to draw in. All drawing will be in the rectangle that you defined.

```
Rectangle scissors = new Rectangle(); 
Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix(), clipBounds, scissors); 
ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors); 
spriteBatch.draw(...); 
spriteBatch.flush();    
ScissorStack.popScissors();
```

> This will limit rendering to within the bounds of the rectangle "clipBounds". 
>   It is also possible push multiple rectangles. Only the pixels of the sprites that are within all of the rectangles will be rendered.

From http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsScissors

Comment: I have tried this, but it's not the way I want. This is clipping, which means `spriteBatch` still draws on the whole screen, but it only renders a portion of the screen. What I want is to have `spriteBatch` really draw on just a portion of the screen

Comment: You may want to update your question to make it clear that you do not want clipping, as it was not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Before rendering the batch, you can set the viewport to draw on a specific screen area. The important line is:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(x, y, w, h);
```

The viewport usually starts at x = 0 and y = 0 and extends to the full width and height of the screen. If we want to see only a part of that original viewport, we need to change both the size and the starting position. To draw only on the left half of the screen, use:

```
x = 0;
y = 0;
w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2;
h = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902373/split-screen-in-libgdx/17903478#17903478) and originally answered [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67024/how-do-i-crop-a-cameras-viewport/87320#87320) to a slightly more complicated problem, but the technique is the same.

To focus on any different portion of the viewport, simply choose x, y, w, and h accordingly. If you're going to do any more rendering in the normal fashion, make sure to reset the viewport with the original x, y, w, and h values.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but could you not just double the viewport width, setting it to 640 instead of 320?

```
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch;
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4().setToOrtho(0, 640, 0, 240, -1, 1));
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 0, 0);
spriteBatch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either

- double the viewport width of the `SpriteBatch`
- use a `Sprite` and set its width scale to **0.5f** (be careful about the origin) and use its `draw(SpriteBatch)` method to draw it.